# xsl:if first and last node not retrieved

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ExistingReservations>
    <reservations>
        <reservation>
            <type>1</type>
            <start_time>2019-03-09T16:11:14Z</start_time>
            <stop_time>2019-03-09T16:23:23Z</stop_time>
        </reservation>
        <reservation>
            <type>2</type>
            <start_time>2019-03-09T11:23:12Z</start_time>
            <stop_time>2019-03-09T11:32:18Z</stop_time>
        </reservation>
        <reservation>
            <type>2</type>
            <start_time>2019-03-09T12:23:12Z</start_time>
            <stop_time>2019-03-09T12:32:18Z</stop_time>
        </reservation>
    </reservations>
</ExistingReservations>
```

I want to only look at reservations of type '2' and then get the range of dates. i.e. the first start_time and the last end time.

But i'm struggling with my xsl as I can't seem to get the first and last positions.

My xsl is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="ExistingReservations">
        <ReservationSchedule>
            <xsl:for-each select="//reservation">
                <xsl:if test="type='2'">
                    <period>
                        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                            <start_time><xsl:value-of select="start_time"/><start_time>
                        </xsl:if>

                        <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                            <end_time><xsl:value-of select="stop_time"/></end_time>
                        </xsl:if>

                    </period>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ReservationSchedule>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So I want to transform to the following:

```
<ReservationSchedule>
    <period>
        <start_time>2019-03-09T11:23:12Z</start_time>
        <end_time>2019-03-09T12:32:18Z</end_time>
    </period>
</ReservationSchedule>
```

I think in the `<xsl:if test="position()=1">` is not working because it's looking at the first node whichi s type 1.. i.e. it's igoring the `<xsl:if test="type='2'">` logic.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `xsl:for-each` selects all reservations, so `position()` will be based on that selected node set. The `xsl:if` will not affect the `position()` function.

What you need to do is change the `select` statement itself, so only reservations of type 2 are selected in the first place

```
<xsl:template match="ExistingReservations">
    <ReservationSchedule>
        <xsl:for-each select="//reservation[type='2']">
            <period>
                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                    <start_time><xsl:value-of select="start_time"/></start_time>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                    <end_time><xsl:value-of select="stop_time"/></end_time>
                </xsl:if>
            </period>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ReservationSchedule>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, you can do away with the `xsl:for-each` and write it like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="ExistingReservations">
        <ReservationSchedule>
            <xsl:variable name="type2s" select="//reservation[type='2']" />
            <period>
                <start_time><xsl:value-of select="$type2s[1]/start_time"/></start_time>
                <end_time><xsl:value-of select="$type2s[last()]/stop_time"/></end_time>
            </period>
        </ReservationSchedule>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ah right yes. I thouht it must of been some simple Xpath. <xsl:for-each select="//reservation[type='2']"> THANKS!!